# Does local VNC over a cellular tether consume data?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vnc

My girlfriend and I do a good bit of VNC screen sharing on our Macs while working. We like to go work in coffee shops, but sometimes we don't have the best of internet connections. We currently have a 12gb data plan with Verizon with tether enabled. I'm wondering, if we're both connected to my tether and using VNC over the local network, it shouldn't consume any of my data, correct? Is there any way that this could consume any data? Local networking is generally never seen by an ISP, but I'm not sure if cell phone tethers work in a different way or send data to the carrier about usage that could cause slow theoretical data drain. Can anybody verify that local VNC over a cell phone tether will not drain data?

Comment: You could look at your data usage and make note of it, then tether for an hour, then re check your data usage, if ok try it for a longer period. You should be able to monitor data usage on your phone directly.

Comment: That's actually what I'm trying right now, but that's kind of unreliable because we're using the web right now and streaming music. I figured I should be able to get an estimate this way though. I just figured someone here might have some actual experience in the area or some more insight.